# Writing '\n' to a file using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to write the string `\n` (not a new line, but the literal string) to a file. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: What's the problem? You don't know how to write to a file, or you don't know how to get a literal backslash + n?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I know how to write a file, but not write \n to said file.

Comment: Just escape the character - \\n

Comment: Like this: `"\\n"`. The escape sequence for a literal backslash is two backslashes.

Answer (score 3):

**[Escape characters in javascript and node.js](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/tutorial/javascript_escape_characters.cfm)** is `\` **backslash**.

Therefore put one extra `\` backslash before your string `\n`

**String:** `\\n`

**Output:** `\n`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are asking about how to escape the `'\n'` so it doesn't get interpreted as a newline, that's just doubling the \ character: `'\\n'`.  How to write to a file is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you need to escape the backslash (\). You can do it like this:

```
const literalNewline = `This is a newline character: \\n`;
fs.writeFileSync('newline.txt', literalNewline);
```

Without the escaped backslash I get this:

> This is a newline character:

When I escape the character I get the result I'm looking for:

> This is a newline character: \n